# How to iterate in Julia?

Tags: for-loop, conditional-statements, julia, ijulia-notebook

I'm trying to make a simple iteration process in Julia (language that I just began to learn) and I'm having some troubles. I want to evaluate the expression  x > 0 && x <= 3 for values ranging from 0 to 3 in order to see when condition is true. I've tried so many ways and I can't find something in documentation which could help me. This is the code I just made (I tried many other combinations) but it's still not working:

```
x = [0,1,2,3]

for i in x
    if x > 0 && x <= 3 == true
        println("true")
    else
        println("false")
    end
```

I'm getting this message error:

```
syntax: incomplete: "for" at In[29]:3 requires end

Stacktrace:
 [1] include_string(::String, ::String) at .\loading.jl:522
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to end the for loop as well, you only ended the if statement.

```
for i in x
    if i > 0 && i <= 3
        println("true")
    else
        println("false")
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error: MethodError: no method matching isless(::Int64, ::Array{Int64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  isless(::Real, ::AbstractFloat) at operators.jl:97
  isless(::Real, ::Real) at operators.jl:266

Stacktrace:
 [1] <(::Int64, ::Array{Int64,1}) at .\operators.jl:194
 [2] macro expansion at .\In[35]:2 [inlined]
 [3] anonymous at .\<missing>:?
 [4] include_string(::String, ::String) at .\loading.jl:522

:/

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera Corrected it, you were checking the array not the loop variable

Comment: You can use `0 < i <= 3` instead of `i > 0 && i <= 3`.

Comment: @DNF Actually I don't know the language, so ... :) But thank you.